# Can a malicious computer on a link local network cause harm on another network?

Tags: network

If I had a firewall with two interfaces - one to an internal private network and the other on a link local network (169.254.0.0) - and sent all questionable requests to the link local computer, could a virus on that computer get access to the private network?

Comment: What prevents me from creating a request that does not meet your definition of questionable that contains an exploit?

Comment: @GlenPierce, 'questionable' in this case was an generalization for 'IP Address' from this question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/193393/advised-to-block-all-traffic-to-from-specific-ip-addresses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A virus is just a computer program. If `Computer A` can communicate with `Computer B` by any means, a virus on `Computer A` can reach `Computer B`. Reach, not necessarily infect.

To a virus infect `Computer B`, it must use a vulnerability, usually remote code execution. On a network where all computers share the same OS version and the same group of applications, usually infecting one computer via network is enough to infect all others.

If the firewall allows traffic from link local to the other network, any virus on `Computer A` have the possibility of reaching `Computer B`.

Comment: So as long as the firewall doesn't become infected, the link local computer cannot infect computers on the private network?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a link local IP address should not be routed out of the current network segment as it only has value on the local link and is there to provide services on the local link only. Or stated another way, no properly designed router (i.e. L3 device, like your firewall) will forward traffic from a local link address off the local link.

So, yes, a device with a local link address that is infected with malicious software of any kind should not be able to reach any device not on the local link. As such it would not be able to spread the malicious software off of the local link.

However your described situation has a number of flaws. The first and foremost is that 169.254.0.0/16 address should not be assigned manually or by DHCP server to any device, as per [RFC3927](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927). This will make any sort of configuration difficult (if even possible in the first place) and subject to interruption in the process should the associated address change.

Answer (score -2):

Computer virus' are nothing but files. So, yes it is possible for the infected file to transfer from one system to another. The effect of the incoming malicious file on the receiving computer will depend upon its vulnerability.

Comment: You have repeated exactly what the other answer says. We expect that answers are unique or have a unique perspective.